# Getting runtime errors with QWebPage

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a Qt GUI application but I haven't touched anything regarding the GUI. I have modified mainwindow.cpp and the project file.

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebFrame>

QWebPage page;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(page.mainFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(pageLoaded1(bool)));
    QUrl router("http://192.168.1.1");
    page.mainFrame()->load(router);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

untitled.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-05-01T23:48:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui webkit webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library
---------------------------
Debug Error!

Program: ...tled-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\debug\untitled.exe
Module: 5.0.2
File: global\qglobal.cpp
Line: 1977

ASSERT: "!"No style available without QApplication!"" in file kernel\qapplication.cpp, line 962

(Press Retry to debug the application)
---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

Extra characters are inserted here to bypass character requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main.cpp`, make sure you create an application object, even if you don't use directly:

```
QApplication app;

// Below you can then create the window
```

**Edit**

The problem is that you are creating a `QWebPage` as a global object, and before the `QApplication` has been created. To solve the problem, make the page a member of the `MainWindow` class. Also make the page a pointer, otherwise you will get other problems.

i.e. in `mainwindow.h`:

```
private:

    QWebPage* page;
```

in `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebFrame>

// Remove this!!
// QWebPage page;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Create the page here:
    page = new QWebPage(this);

    connect(page.mainFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(pageLoaded1(bool)));
    QUrl router("http://192.168.1.1");
    page.mainFrame()->load(router);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```